# Only specify part of generator return type, and leave rest implicit

Tags: typescript

I have a generator function `lex` that yields values of the shape

```typescript
| { readonly kind: "char"; readonly text: string; }
| { readonly kind: "number"; readonly text: string; }
| ...;
```

I'm using the following type to `infer` this shape:

```typescript
export type Token = ReturnType<typeof lex> extends Generator<infer T>
  ? T
  : never;
```

This all works fine. I would now like to specify what type of values can be sent back to the Generator via the `.next(val)` function. How can I specify the third generic argument to the Generator type (`Generator<_, _, Next>`) while still being able to infer the first type?

The following doesn't do what I want:

```typescript
function* lex(): Generator<unknown, unknown, Next> {
  const a = yield { kind: "number", text: "123" };
  // a is Next...
}

type Token = ReturnType<typeof lex> extends Generator<infer T>
  ? T
  : never;
// ...but Token is unknown
```

Answer (score 0):

While writing this question I figured out a solution that works, but feels a little hacky, so I'll leave it here in case somebody finds this question and nobody has found a better solution:

```typescript
type Next = number; // or whatever else you want

const lex = function* () {
  let text = "123";
  const a = yield { kind: "number", text } as const;
  // a is Next..
} satisfies () => Generator<unknown, unknown, Next>

type Token = ReturnType<typeof lex> extends Generator<infer T>
  ? T
  : never;
// ...and Token is { readonly kind: "number"; readonly text: string; }
```